# Universal image loader and Picasso not loading some of image URLs

Tags: android, universal-image-loader, picasso, imageurl, imagedownload

I'm using a listView in my android app and it has a textView and an imageView.
Getting from the web service URLs I want to show into imageView.
But Many image URLs is not loading. I tried "Android universal image loader" and "Picasso" for downloading image URLs. I tried these APIs sample applications with my image URLs and same result. 
The image URLs work. All images are opened in the browser.
Why are some images loaded some images not loading? I do not understand why.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Can you post more details? For example, some of the URLs - preferable some that work and some that don't.

Comment: Could you show us your stacktrace? UIL displays Log errors for failed images. We can start from there

Comment: Maybe to much threads operating on bitmaps and therefore somewhere occurs `OutOfMemoryError` Try setting in UIL one thread and put this in your default config `.bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)` and `.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)`

Comment: This is the error in LogCat: E/ImageLoader(13271): java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://m.a***.com/images/catalog/84208/25458.jpg My url begins with www. but it seems m. in logcat

Comment: Then then server is redirecting your request to the mobile endpoint.

Comment: I tried four different image download api and none of them was not the solution. @Pedro If the problem is related to the server what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your server is changing the request URL to mobile and the images doesn't exist in the mobile server. Forcing UIL to use another agent should make the server not redirect your request.

Try this with UIL on your DisplayImageOptions

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("User-Agent","");
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
.showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.dummyhotelimage)
.showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.dummyhotelimage)
.cacheInMemory(true)
.cacheOnDisk(true)
.considerExifParams(true)
.extraForDownloader(headers)
.bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
.build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getActivity()).imageDownloader(new CustomImageDownloader(context)).build());
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(fullImageUrl, holder.img_hotel, options);
```

Then create a custom ImageDownloader

```
public class CustomImageDownaloder extends BaseImageDownloader {

    public CustomImageDownaloder(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomImageDownaloder(Context context, int connectTimeout, int readTimeout) {
        super(context, connectTimeout, readTimeout);
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(String url, Object extra) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection conn = super.createConnection(url, extra);
        Map<String, String> headers = (Map<String, String>) extra;
        if (headers != null) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> header : headers.entrySet()) {
                conn.setRequestProperty(header.getKey(), header.getValue());
            }
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/340

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately did not work

Comment: Does the stacktrace looks the same? FileNotFoundException for url with m.*.jpg?

Comment: yes correct, looks the same error in stacktrace

Comment: I've update the whole code again. Try again. Good luck

Comment: it works fine finally. Thank you so much your answers.You've helped me a lot.